# dart error - could not start pub serve or connect to pub

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to run [this](https://www.dartlang.org/samples/dndfiles/) drag and drop API. When I try to run the dart file (with the dart editor) I get the following error:

`could not start pub serve or connect to pub`.

I'm not very familiar with dart. Where's my error?

Answer (score 2):

Either you have another service listening on port `8080` (there is an open issue to make the port `pub serve` is using configurable) or there is already a `pub serve` instance running (I had this occassionally, that `pub serve` kept running after DartEditor crashed).

If it is the later, end DartEditor and check in the TaskManger (Windows) if any `Dart` process is still running and kill all if any, and then start DartEditor and try again.

Comment: Thanks @Gunter but I don't think that's the problem... while the API that I mentioned throws this error, [this](https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/darrrt/) demo seems to work... I can't tell why, both codes aren't mine.

Comment: That's not an API that throws the error, the error is thrown when DartEditor tries to launch `pub serve` a web server which serves your page to the browser while developing, debugging and testing with Dartium.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're trying to run the correct file. When running any file from the `lib/` subdirectory, for example, `pub` will refuse to serve and — unfortunately — Dart Editor chooses to show the cryptic "could not start pub serve or connect to pub" message.

Click on the little black down arrow (▼) next to the green Run icon and make sure you're not running something other than you want.

[image]

(Dart Editor defaults to running the last Dart file you tried to run unless you specify otherwise.)